# Ember Data automatic refresh after save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The Ember page I'm working on is to display a of grid of operators and their jobs and have that list automatically update when the user creates a new job.  My current best attempt will draw pre-existing jobs on page load, but the page doesn't refresh with any new jobs created using 'saveNewJob' even though I can see the new job in the Data view of Ember Inspector.

Here's the code with some '..snip..' inserted to focus on the important parts:

routes/scheduler.js

```
export default ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       return { 
          jobs: this.store.query('job', {
             location: session.location,
             date: session.selectedDate
          },
          operators: this.store.query('operator', {
             location: session.location
          }
       }
    },
    action: {
      saveNewJob: function(params) {
        var newJob = this.store.createRecord('job',{
           //job properties from params
        };
        var thisRoute = this;
        newJob.save().then(function(){ thisRoute.refresh() });
      }
    }
}
```

templates/scheduler.hbs

```
..snip..
{{#each model.operators as |op|}}
  {{operator-row operator=op jobs=model.jobs}}
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

templates/components/operator-row.hbs

```
   <!-- Draw the grid for the operator -->
   ..snip..
   <!--Draw jobs over grid -->
   {{#if jobs.isFulfilled}}
     {{#each jobsForOperator as |job|}}
       {{operator-job job=job}}
     {{/each}}
   {{/if}}
```

component/operator-row.js

```
jobsForOperator: Ember.computed('jobs', function() {
  var opId = this.operator.get('id');
  var retVal this.jobs.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('operator').get('id') === opId;
  });
  <!-- Append some drawing properties to each job in retVal -->
  ..snip...
},
..snip..
```

I haven't seen a need to add anything to controller/scheduler.  The operator-job component is a simple div that uses the drawing properties to correctly place/draw the div in the operator row.

There are various ways for a new job to be created, but I purposefully left them out because they all end up calling 'saveNewJob' and I am able to get a console.log statement to fire from there.

One solution I've tried is adding a 'this.store.findAll('job');' at the start of the model function and then using 'jobs: this.store.filter('job', function() { })' to create the model.jobs property.  That sees neither the existing jobs nor the newly created job returned despite seeing my date and location matches return true.

So what am I doing wrong here?  Is there a better way to get this refresh to happen automatically?  Appreciate any help you all can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function for just this case [DS.Store.filter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter). You use it instead of query. Something like this:

```
let filteredJobs = this.store.filter(
    'job',
    {location: session.location, date: session.selectedDate},
    job => job.get('location') === session.location && job.get('date') === session.selectedDate
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  It looks like this is working as expected and my issue is really that Mirage is not returning the new data.  

One question: do I still need to use refresh() in my route or will this automatically update things without the refresh?

Comment: No need for refresh, it will update automatically when new items enter store.